Override one method at the class level
I dislike Python's native string for complex numbers, and so wrote my own:
def str (z):
    result = f"{z.real}"
    if (z.imag < 0.0):
        result += " - "
    else:
        result += " + "
    result += f"{abs(z.imag)}i"
    return result

I saw the article here about overriding a function at the instance level, but is it possible to override str in complex's class?  That is, any complex number I instance would use my str function?

You can't patch the __str__ method of a built-in class like complex, unfortunately.

Depending on what it is you don't like about the built-in __str__, you might be able to use __format__. I don't think you can force whitespace around the + or -, but you can provide float-style formatting to apply to each component of the complex number.
